# Can I get the full rows when using group by multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregation, rank

If the date, item, and category are the same in the table,
I'd like to treat it as the same row and return n rows out of them(ex: if n is 3, then limit 0, 3).

```
------------------------------------------
id   |  date   | item   | category   | ...
------------------------------------------
101  | 20220201| pencil | stationery | ...    <---
------------------------------------------        |  treat as same result
105  | 20220201| pencil | stationery | ...    <---  
------------------------------------------
120  | 20220214| desk   | furniture  | ...
------------------------------------------
125  | 20220219| tongs  | utensil    | ...    <---
------------------------------------------        |  treat as same
129  | 20220219| tongs  | utensil    | ...    <--- 
------------------------------------------
130  | 20220222| tongs  | utensil    | ...
```

expected results (if n is 3)

```
-----------------------------------------------
id   |  date   | item   | category   | ... rank
-----------------------------------------------
101  | 20220201| pencil | stationery | ...  1  
-----------------------------------------------       
105  | 20220201| pencil | stationery | ...  1  
-----------------------------------------------
120  | 20220214| desk   | furniture  | ...  2
-----------------------------------------------
125  | 20220219| tongs  | utensil    | ...  3
-----------------------------------------------
129  | 20220219| tongs  | utensil    | ...  3
```

The problem is that I have to bring the values of each group as well.
If I have only one column to group by, I can compare id value with origin table, but I don't know what to do with multiple columns.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

For reference, I used a user variable to compare it with previous values,
I couldn't use it because the duration was slow.

```
          SELECT 
            *,
            IF(@prev_date=date and @prev_item=item and @prev_category=category,@ranking, @ranking:=@ranking+1) AS sameRow,
            @prev_item:=item,
            @prev_date:= date,
            @prev_category:=category,
            @ranking
          FROM ( SELECT ...
```

I'm using Mysql 8.0 version and id value is not a continuous number because I have to order by before group by.

Comment: What do you mean by `and bring 10`?  Can you include your expected results here?

Comment: I added expected results! 
I think it's a bit like comparing value with a dense rank (), but having multiple columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly, you can try to use `dense_rank` window function and set `order by` with your expected columns

if `date` column can represent the order number I would put it first.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,dense_rank() OVER(ORDER BY date, item, category) rnk
    FROM T 
) t1
```

[SQLFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0f3706f4c99dc8fc9725e2103a4f1ba1)

Answer (score 1):

Window functions come in very handy in this situation. But for those of us still using MySQL 5.7, where functions such as row_number don't exist, we have to either resort to using a user variable and resetting the value every time before the main statement, or defining the user variable directly in the statement.
method 1

```
set @row_id=0; -- remember to reset the row_id to 0 every time before the main query below
select id,date,item,category,rank from testtb join 
    (
    select date,item,category, (@row_id:=@row_id+1) as rank
        from 
            (select date,item,category  from testtb group by date,item,category) t1
    ) t2 
using(date,item,category);
```

method 2

```
select id,date,item,category,rank from testtb join 
    (
    select date,item,category, (@row_id:=@row_id+1) as rank
        from 
            (select date,item,category  from testtb group by date,item,category) t1, (select @row_id := 0) as n
    ) t2 
using(date,item,category);
```

Comment: Thank you! I’ve learned a lot from you :)

Comment: Why not a simple `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @Rick James, would you please elaborate ? I am not sure I understand how to simplify it in this case. I would really appreciate your kindness.

Comment: The subquery returning t1 is to sort rows in group by said columns. t2 is to add the row_id, which can not be done in t1 as it would be based on each single row from the base table before being sorted into group.  And the main query is to add the final column i.e id to the result set : )